# Limit Jekyll Tags displayed on Home Page

Tags: tags, jekyll, liquid

I want to display the most recent Tags from the latest blog Post on my home page (or limit it to perhaps 6).

My code so far shows every tag:

```
<div class="archive-tags">
    {% for post in site.posts %}
    {% if post.tags != empty %}
      {% for tag in post.tags %}
          <a href="{{site.baseurl}}/tags/#{{tag|slugify}}">{{ tag }}</a>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

And i'd like to know what markup to use to limit this or show only the most recent blog post tags.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to what i was looking for was a simple as adding `limit: 1`.

The amended working code is now:

```
<div class="archive-tags">
{% for post in site.posts limit: 1 %}
{% if post.tags != empty %}
  {% for tag in post.tags %}
      <a href="{{site.baseurl}}/tags/#{{tag|slugify}}">{{ tag }}</a>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Finished/desired result here: https://linksoftheweek.co.uk/